# Icon not showing up in mpdf

Tags: icons, font-awesome, mpdf

The check-icon(font-awesome) I use  works perfectly in my page but when I converted the page to mpdf it is not showing up. I tried with " ✔ " too but no hope. Please suggest a way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got a solution.**

> 1. **Removed** font-awesome css.
> 2. **Included** bootstrap.min.css.
> 3. Used ✔ [&_#_10004;  //Remove underscores]. 
>      **Note**: Even after including bootstrap.min.css the bootstrap glyphicon didn't work. So i used ✔ instead. 
>      (I also tried ✔ without bootstrap.min.css, but didn't work.)